# jQuery - Checking to see what state the slideToggle is in

Tags: jquery

I'm not a very good jQuery coder. Actually I'm new and terrible and I was wondering if someone could help me out.

I have a bunch of divs which I'm using `slideToggle` on to display options. The code I have at the moment works. But I want to do when someone clicks the link is to check to see if there are any 'open' slidetoggles. If there are, close them and just open the one that i clicked on.

I'm sure my current code is not good, so any help on cleaning it up and adding this functionality would be greatly appreciated.

The code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#parent-print").click(function(e) {
        jQuery("#child-print").slideToggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    jQuery("#parent-web").click(function(e) {
        jQuery("#child-web").slideToggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    jQuery("#parent-inspiration").click(function(e) {
        jQuery("#child-inspiration").slideToggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
if( jQuery('#parent-web').is(':hidden') ){..}
```

http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: As an offtopic, if you used `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` instead of `jQuery(document).ready(function()`, you will be able to use `$` inside your codes. For example `$('#parent-web')` instead of `jQuery('#parent-web')`

Comment: Oh dang, i didnt know that one ... Thanks for that